# Finding Similar Or Alike Keywords From String PHP

Tags: php, substring

Case 1:

```
$tofind= "The Flash Tv Show";
$tags= array("flash-new","netflix","article","season");
foreach ($tags as $key => $tag)
{  
    if (preg_match("/$tofind/",$tag))
    {
      echo 'true';
    }
    else
    {
        echo'false';
    }
}`
```

What I Want In Return : "flash-new" Tag From $tags Array

Case 2 :

```
$tofind = "PHP Development Artice";
$array = array("java","develop","post");
```

Return I Want : develop

Case 3 :

```
$tofind = "StackOverflow Questions";
$array = array("stack Overflow","sql","php");
```

Return I want : stack overflow

Comment: have you tried [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) ?

Comment: You need to separate `$tofind` to individual words. Also will need the `i` modifier so it is case insensitive. You also will need to split `$tags` on `-`s.

Comment: Thx @mistermartin similar_text Works Fine