# Getting Max Value From Multi Dimensional Array Using max Function

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
<?php
$heading = "The Flash 3";
$arrays = array("the-flash","tv-shows","games","videos");
$playerdata = array();
foreach ($arrays as $key => $tag) {
similar_text($tag, $heading, $percent); 
$playerdata = array(
'tag' => $tag,
'goals' => $percent
 );   
 $allplayerdata[] = $playerdata;
 }
 print_r($allplayerdata);
 ?>
Result Of print_r($allplayerdata);
([0] => Array ( [tag] => the-flash [goals] => 60 ) 
[1] => Array ([tag] => tv-shows [goals] => 21.052631578947 ) 
[2] => Array ( [tag] => games [goals] => 25 ) 
[3] => Array ( [tag] => videos [goals] => 23.529411764706 ) )
```

All I Need Is Max Value And Name Of Tag i.e the-flash and goals = 60
Values Are Coming From DB.. Thnx

Comment: On my assumption, if you only querying to get `max` then trying using it Database

Comment: I think it would be best if you show us your database table schema so that we can help you come up with a better database query, that way you dont have to worry about looping in PHP. Faster results. How are you currently obtaining your database info?

Comment: Yes I Need Max Goals And Tag From $allplayerdata Array's Result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167887/finding-similar-or-alike-keywords-from-string-php .. It all lead me here to this

Comment: I Just Want To Check Is There Any Tag Releates To The Title Of Page @CodeGodie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167887/finding-similar-or-alike-keywords-from-string-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your `foreach` loop with this:

```
$max = $max_tag = NULL;
foreach ($arrays as $tag) {
    similar_text($tag, $heading, $percent); 
    $playerdata = array(
        'tag' => $tag,
        'goals' => $percent
    );   
    $allplayerdata[] = $playerdata;
    if (is_null($max) || $percent > $max) {
        $max = $percent;
        $max_tag = $tag;
    }
}
echo "Max = {$max}, max tag = {$max_tag}";
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function isnull()

Comment: thanks for fix, @Spikolynn ;)